# Run a python script, observe in terminal and save to a file

Tags: python-3.x, logging, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run a python script in Ubuntu and see the output in the terminal and simultaneously save the output to a file. I already know how to save the output to a .txt file. But when I run this, I don't see anything in terminal. I have to keep reloading the text file to see the output:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

for mode in modes:
    log_path = 'Logs/log%s.txt'
    for scriptInstance in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        sys.stdout = open(log_path % scriptInstance, 'w')
        subprocess.call('python3 main.py',
                          stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: Does it have to be done in Python?  `python3 main.py | tee log.txt` would give you both forms of output.

Comment: So I'm trying to benchmark this code with different arguments to `main.py` and also do this several time as you can see I have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I don't want to come back to the computer several times and run the code with different arguments

Answer (score 0):

You should check out python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html). You could use a [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) to log to the terminal and use a [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) to log to a file.

Check this [logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).